# Python PIL create gif fails

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I was trying to create a gif using PIL as explained in:
http://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/pillow/creating-animated-gif/

And the code they show to save a bunch of images "names" into a gif:

```
# Open all the frames
images = []

for n in names:
    frame = Image.open(n)
    images.append(frame)

# Save the frames as an animated GIF
images[0].save('anicircle.gif',
               save_all=True,
               append_images=images[1:],
               duration=100,
               loop=0)
```

However, when saving the gif it only saves one image, what I am doing wrong?
I am using PIL version 1.1.7 in python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your code. I would check what Pillow version you are using.

```
from PIL import Image
Image.PILLOW_VERSION
```

`append_images` was added in Pillow 3.4.0, so you will want to use at least that version.